# .NET or C# code to perform stream-to-block operations on socket input

Tags: .net, stream, block

Is there some open-source library or code snippet that performs stream-to-block operation with all the bells and whistles?

I am looking for some code where you specify the start/ end characters and the code does all the receiving from the stream, all the checking for correct pairing for start/ end characters and then returns one or more block built from that stream data.

Thanks in advance

Mario

Answer (score 0):

What about using each line as a block

```
// Sender
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
sw.WriteLine("first block");
sw.WriteLine("second block");

// Reciever
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
string block1 = sr.ReadLine();
string block2 = sr.ReadLine();
```

Comment: That is too simple for two reason: (1) no support for start chars (2) fixed end char.